# Android - Making A Notification Manager - .NET

Tags: android, .net, notifications, android-notifications

So I'm new to Android development but I've been a C++ developer for 25 years and a C# developer for almost 13 years, so I'm no beginner to code. But I am, by trade, a video game developer and I'm trying to make a notification sound manager app and have literally NO idea where to start. From what I search, I only seem to find how to make my own notifications. Not what I want.

Background: I am a nerd and I like to use various video game sounds and music, and TV show sound clips (Simpsons, Family Guy, etc) as my notification sounds and ringtones, for everything. I have downloaded many, MANY sound clips (dozens from Warcraft II, thousands for the various Zelda games, hundreds or more for various Mario game; probably several thousand in all), but I can't always remember which clips I used for which contacts, apps, etc. I want to make a program that keeps track of which clips were used for which contacts, or whatever app notification users choose. I have 3rd party apps, like ToneSelector, which allow me to choose sound files in a similar way for particular notifications, separate from the usual Android UI. I want to essentially EXTEND that functionality and make a similar app, however, it can reference all notification categories and note what sounds are used and where. Whether it keeps a small database, or just scans real-time, I would like to make an app that knows when I've used a particular sound file for some other system-wide purpose. I am trying to write this in C#/.NET, but any help is ok with me!

What classes do I need to familiarize myself with or what documents/tutorials do I need to find?

I am very new to Android development, so I haven't tried much. I have Googled a bunch, but again, all I find is how to create my own notifications. I want to, ultimately, adjust other apps' notifictions.